# Choose specific files to download in utorrent ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, utorrent, ubuntu-14.04

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and i am using uTorrent web UI. Whenever i add a torrent for downloading, it straight away starts downloading. I want to be able to choose which files to download and which files to exclude. Is there a way of doing so ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the lower windows of the web UI, there's a tab called files, click in there, there you have a list of the files being downloaded. Right click on the files you dont want to download and choose "Don't download"

alternative solution:
by double clicking in the particular file in the "files" tab you can switch priority between "low", "normal", "high" and "**skip**"